# Remmina VNC Hangs on Connecting to Headless Mini-PC

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I am trying to connect a laptop (as client) to a headless mini-pc (as server) both running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit on a home router. I can SSH perfectly fine in terminal or Remmina (after allowing port 22 with `ufw`) just unable to remotely connect with VNC in Remmina 1.2.0 as dialog hangs.

- Laptop is connected to wifi with active listening ports:

  ```
  $ netstat -ln --inet --inet6

  Active Internet connections (only servers)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
  tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
  ```
- Mini-PC (Intel Celeron, 4-processor, 64-GB HD, 2GB RAM) is connected via ethernet to same router. It boots up without login directly to the root user (at least seen with a temp monitor).

  I tried auto-connecting mini-PC to wifi (even adjusted the [`/etc/network/interfaces`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412325/automatically-connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-cli) file but not with static IP (could that be issue?) and with a saved wireless profile *available to all users* but it never connects wirelessly). Below are active listening ports from ssh:

  ```
  $ netstat -ln --inet --inet6

  Active Internet connections (only servers)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
  tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN     
  tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
  ```

Below is my setup file where the server is auto-filled per selection in the `[...]` browse button. And yes, mini-PC does allow remote desktop sharing, view and control.

[image: Remmina Connection File]

Upon connecting, my heart leaps as I am prompted for SSH password via tunnel and then the VNC passcode. However, after that the *Connecting...* dialog as shown below simply hangs forever. My heart sinks. Absolutely nothing happens! No error message, no additional prompts, nothing. Epic frustration.

[image: Remmina Connection Dialog[2]]

I tried the IP address for *Server* as shown by `nmap`, different hostnames, different ports as shown with `netstat`, even changes to *Advanced* in Remmina. Though the hanging dialog does not appear with these other changes, they error out with *failed to bind on local port*.

No where I found on askubuntu has anyone had the hanging Remmina dialog. Only on this [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072078) post with nearly same networking setup touched on the hanging *Connect* where at end they discussed ports but sadly our good friend leaves us with no closure.

Please advise on how to troubleshoot and being a new Linux user please provide specific command lines as I do not know much of the lingo. Is it port forwarding of internet provider? Is it device hardware issue? Ethernet not compatible with wireless? Firewalls of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found my answer: no **vncserver** was installed on the mini-PC (*facepalm*) and possibly why the *Connecting...* dialog simply hung waiting for a VNC session.

Simply I did the following:

1. Installed `tightvncserver`, created vncserver password, and adjusted the startup file.

   ```
   $ sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver

   $ mv ~/.vnc/xstartup ~/.vnc/xstartup.bak
   $ gedit ~/.vnc/xstartup
   $ sudo chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup
   ```
2. Then in ssh, started the vncserver on mini-PC.

   ```
   $ vncserver
   ```
3. Finally, on laptop client, I opened the port.

   ```
   $ ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username server_ip_address
   ```

   And then with Remmina I logged in connecting to `localhost:5901` entering the ssh password (for tunnel) and vncserver password created above in step #1.

[image: VNC Remote Desktop Screenshot]