# Automatically connect Ubuntu to a specific WiFi at startup

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04. I want the system to connect to a particular WiFi network automatically when it boots; it can be a new connection which the system has not connected to earlier.
For example: SSID = *wireless*; password = *abcde*

I have tried suggestions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412325/automatically-connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-cli) question but they did not work for me (the system kept connecting to one of the previously known networks).

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the interface file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the informations about the WiFi you want to connect to :

```
network={
ssid="testing"
psk="testingPassword"
}
```

Comment: Also, just to make sure, the ssid and psk are written without the `" "`, right?

Comment: Mmhh, It works with them , but maibe they are not mandatory

Comment: Tried with and then without quotes, it's still connecting to the previously known network, and not the one specified in `interfaces` file.

Comment: It might have something to do with wifi priority, you could try to 'forget' the known wifi in order to be sure that the added network connection works and, if yes, you can try to change the priority with one of these methods :https://askubuntu.com/questions/165679/how-to-manage-available-wireless-network-priority